# Подскажите jquery плагин для создания рейтинга из 5 звёзд?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

здравствуйте. Мне нужно сверстать рейтинг. Причём у меня его аж 3 типоразмера. Подскажите jquery лёгкий в обращении чтобы можно было сделать так как на скрине:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/BioPhoton/css-star-rating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [jquery-star-rating](https://github.com/irfan/jquery-star-rating)
- [css-star-ratings](https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/)
- [jquery star rating](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/)
- [jquery rating
  plugin](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-rating-plugin/)
- [список плагинов с рентингом](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем плагин, но, думаю, будет полезно знать как это можно достаточно просто реализовать самому.

```js
$(function() {
  var $formSubmit = $('.rating__submit'),
      $star = $('.stars__label'),
      $input = $star.find('input'),
      $result = $('.result span');

  $star.click(function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('checked') ) {
      $star.removeClass('checked');
      $(this).addClass('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('checked');
      $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  
  $formSubmit.click(function() {
    $input.each(function() {
      if( $(this).prop('checked') == true ) {
        $result.text($(this).val());
        return false;
      } else {
        $result.text('NO');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.stars {
  display: flex;
  direction: rtl;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 95px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.stars__label {
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: .15s;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}

.stars__label:hover,
.stars__label:hover ~ .stars__label,
.stars__label.checked,
.stars__label.checked ~ .stars__label {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

.stars__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="rating">
  <div class="stars">
    <label class="stars__label">
      <input type="radio" name="star" value="5" class="stars__input">
    </label>
    <label class="stars__label">
      <input type="radio" name="star" value="4" class="stars__input">
    </label>
    <label class="stars__label">
      <input type="radio" name="star" value="3" class="stars__input">
    </label>
    <label class="stars__label">
      <input type="radio" name="star" value="2" class="stars__input">
    </label>
    <label class="stars__label">
      <input type="radio" name="star" value="1" class="stars__input">
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="rating__submit">Submit</button>
  
  <div class="result">
    Rating: <span></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибище. Я обязательно себе сохраню

Answer (score -1):

```
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" checked="checked"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
```

Используйте jquery для добавление и удаление стилей.
т.к. в HTML нельзя менять input[type='radio'] используйте изображение.

Comment: Если это и ответ, то какой-то неполный. Нет стилей и мало что понятно, как предлагается их писать. Я бы глядя на код решил, что все звезды будут пустые и только посередине закрашенная. Лол, это совсем не то, что просил топикстартер: должно закрашиваться от первой до выделенной звезды (три звезды закрашено - оценка три). И (вздыхая) вы отвечаете не на тот вопрос, который задали: спрашивали плагин, а не код.

Comment: @AK, вордпресс программисты не довольны :DDD

Comment: @VostokSisters конкретнее? Не понимаю замечания.